# How do I add a widget from an Android phone?

Tags: widgets, mobile

Currently my only internet access is via my phone, and I need to add a widget to a Wordpress site. This requires dragging and dropping the widget to the sidebar, which I cannot do via the web browser on the device. Is there some way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes at the top of the page click on "Screen Options" then click **"Enable accessibility mode"**,